# Where is the GoogleAnalyticsObject in the "Alternative Async Tag" of analytics.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

The default **analytics.js** script creates/defines the **GoogleAnalyticsObject**, which I'm using in a Google Analytics integration.

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

However, when the page is not using the default **analytics.js** tag but in the "**Alternative Async Tag**" shown [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs#alternative_async_tag) this object is not defined anymore making the integration fail.

```
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Is there an equivalent object? Is it safe to define **GoogleAnalyticsObject** manually without affecting GA's tracking?